# What problems would you expect when switching from JS to C++?

Tags: javascript, c++

What problems would you expect when switching from JS to C++ ?

Comment: Problems? Do you mean confusions?

Comment: Too numerous to list, that'd be like asking what problems would expect moving from Earth to Mars, sure they're both spheres and revolve around the sun, but that's about where the similarity stops.

Comment: I'm thinking you mean converting from Java to C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is incredibly different from Javascript. A few main differences:

- Static typing (usually types of variables are specified, most types are known at compile time)
- Low level memory management (no GC so you'll have to allocate and free a lot of memory yourself)
- Different object system: C++ is class-based, while Javascript is prototype-based. You'll also have to learn everything that this entails, e.g. access modifiers, class-based inheritance
- Less safety than JS. C++ doesn't hold your hand much like Javascript does, if you don't allocate the right amount of memory or try to access an out-of-bounds array index, etc. your program will crash (and you've introduced a critical security flaw in the program as well)
- Templates and everything that comes with that
- I/O are different, obviously, because you're dealing with files rather than HTML and the DOM.

There are also obviously some trivial differences, e.g. you'll have to compile and link your programs before you execute them. You'll also have to learn a new standard library.

You may also find [this](http://abstrusegoose.com/249) amusing.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a very high level language which has found it's main application in the web. C++ is a very low level language compared to JavaScript. The main difference (painful difference) you will find is that C++ does not have a garbage collector. You need to allocate and free memory by hand.

Comment: "main" difference. Don't forget it's procedural and has a different flavour of OOP. You also have to know pointers, templates and stl those are pretty big.

Comment: If you think the memory allocation feature is the main difference, I suspect you've never dealt with any serious pointer usage.

Comment: Ok, I was vague. I did intended to imply pointers in my response, but I didn't write it.